# Javascript: Arrays in Functions and How to Call Them

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

Very new to everything here, and I know that my question has to be incredibly simple, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out!

I recently bought "Javascript & JQuery" by Jon Duckett (which I am loving by the way). However, when the book begins to get into functions, specifically getting multiple values out of a function on page 95, the following example is used:

```js
function getSize(width, height, depth) {
  var area = width * height;
  var volume = width * height * depth;
  var sizes = [area, volume];
  console.log(sizes);
}

var areaOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[0];
var volumeOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[1];
```

Whenever I run this in my browser I get an error stating that, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined."

If anyone can explain to me, or point me in the right direction as to why calling an index in an array, from a function, with this method is not working for me. I just want to know why this example from the book will not work.

Thank you in advance, and thank you for all that I have learned so far from using this site.

Comment: The function isn't returning anything. It looks like you should have `return sizes` at the end of the function.

Comment: Also, while I'd imagine the book gets to this later, using objects (associative arrays) with named properties is a better approach, i.e. `return {area: area, volume: volume}` and then `let size = getSize(3, 2, 3); let area = size.area; let volume = size.volume`

Comment: Claus JØrgensen, I will definitely look into that. Skipping ahead a bit I do see a bit of info on it. Hopefully I will make it there before ripping my hair out haha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to return the array result from function

```js
function getSize(width, height, depth) {
  var area = width * height;
  var volume = width * height * depth;
  var sizes = [area, volume];
  return sizes;
}

var areaOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[0];
var volumeOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[1];
  console.log(areaOne,volumeOne);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Both Mark Meyer, and prasanth. I just tested it out and it is working. The example in the book does have "return sizes;" at the end of the function, but I forgot that I still need to call it outside. Am I correct in saying that? I am so new at this if you can't tell already hahah.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything as expected by your code: Add the return statement.

```
function getSize(width, height, depth) {
  var area = width * height;
  var volume = width * height * depth;
  var sizes = [area, volume];
  console.log(sizes);
  return [area,volume,sizes];
}

var areaOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[0];
var volumeOne = getSize(3, 2, 3)[1];
```

Comment: sizes contains area and volume

Comment: `var sizes = [area, volume];`...it is useless to return all three; just `return sizes;`